# AdSense related website design / Ad Blending

Tags: website-design, google-adsense, banners

I'm reading websites like [websitepublisher](http://www.websitepublisher.net/) and seen sites like [environmentalchemistry](http://environmentalchemistry.com/). They all have those adsense in them, but the ads seem like perfectly blended.

I want to earn money from a content website, which i want to describe things about human relationships. I prefer to buy templates from ThemeForest and build a website around it.

Would i make a better profit, if the ads are blended like in the first 2 websites or would i be better off with a banner that is placed like in [this modern design](http://themeforest.net/item/premium-pixels-fancy-pants-blog-magazine-theme/full_screen_preview/232838)?

- What are the benefits of these blended ads?
- Would users "leave" the webpage because it looks outdated/oldshool?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see what you mean by the banner on that third link. I can't see where the adverts would go.

Comment: Well the 3rd link may bear a 250X250 banner ad in it, or the posts could have some ads. 
So this means the first two are better?

Answer (score 2):

Google frowns on 'blending' AdSense ads [[source](http://adsense.blogspot.com/2008/03/another-look-at-optimizations.html)]. It's unhealthy for advertisers and frustrating for your visitors:

> "As you can imagine, users who click on ads that they think are publisher-created content may lose trust in your site and decide not to return in the future. It's important to keep their interests in mind, as well as your own."

**It's worth clearly segregating ads and content** because it makes your content more legible and your ads clearly identifiable as adverts. You don't want to trick people into clicking them; you want people to click them when they're genuinely interested in what's on offer.

You asked whether you should mix ads into your content or keep them in the sidebar. I say do both. [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/), for example, has successfully mixed in-post ads with multiple banner ads in a dedicated sidebar, but they still maintain a distinct segregation between ads and content, and that's probably what you should strive for if your goal is to increase clicks without losing visitors.

As to whether you should adopt a 'modern' or 'outdated' design, it's often best not to follow trends, but instead to understand who will be visiting your site and design it around their needs. If you're designing a site for a major bank, for example, it might  be better to shun the grungy vector splatters favoured by many 'modern' web designers and adopt something more traditional instead. If you're designing a dating site for young adults, they'll probably expect something a little more 'modern' in its appearance and functionality.

Comment: Hmmm, thank you for your answer. It enlightens me in some way but i really don't know if people would click the ad's too. Definitely worth trying.

Comment: @Herr Kaleun: They would if the ads were relevant. And they should be relevant if your content is well written.

Comment: @James Skemp, my content "will" be relevant. So there should be no problem